# Probability applied to hash tables

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out the following probability application:

Suppose that we have $n$ possible locations in which we can store $k$ phone numbers. I want to find the probability that any of these locations has more than one phone number stored there.

Here's what I have so far.

We can reframe this problem as considering the complement, where all locations do not have more than one phone number stored within. Only $k$ of $n$  locations will contain a phone number, so we get a factor of ${n \choose k}$. There are $k!$ ways to arrange those $k$ numbers or $k$ unique designations from the hash function. Then, I envisioned the rest of this problem as involving a binomial distribution, where the "successes" are the locations which have a number. Then, the probability that any location will have a phone number is $\frac{1}{n}$, and the probability that a location will not have a phone number is $1 - \frac{1}{n}$, so the probability that $k$ locations will have a number and $n - k$ will not is $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k \cdot \left(1 - \frac{n}{k}\right)^{n-k}$.

Based on that, the tentative answer I come up with is: $1 - \frac{k!{n \choose k} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-k}}{n^k}$.

Is this correct? Is the logic sound?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The first phone number has $n$ options.

The second phone number has $n-1$ options.

The $i$th phone number has $n-i$ options.

Hence the probability of any of these has more than one phone is

\begin{align}
1-\frac{1}{n^k} \prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(n-i) &= 1- \frac1{n^k} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!
}
\end{align}

This is known as the birthday problem.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. This seems to come out differently from my answer, though, which implies that I must have made a mistake. If you wouldn't mind, was there a flaw in the approach that I took above?

Comment: Starting from $\binom{n}{k}$ and then taking the reordering into the consideration by multiplying by $k$ would have fixed all the phone locations, that is you have counted all the possibilities. Just divide by the total number of arrangement without constraint. Also, note that the probability of having a phone in slot $i$ and slot $j$ are not independent.